# The Dinitz problem

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

I would like to ask if someone knows about good books or online articles about The Dinitz problem or maybe someone can explain the problem a little.

> Consider $n^2$ cells arranged in an $( n \times n)$-square, and let $(i,j)$ denote the cell in row $i$ and columns $j$. Suppose that for every cell $(i,j)$ we are given a set $C(i,j)$ of $n$ colors.
>   Is it then always possible to color the whole array by picking for each cell $(i,j)$ a coor from its set $C(i,j)$ such that the colors in each row and each column are distinct?

Comment: so i thinking it is similar to   known  theorem from graph theory

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitz_conjecture

Comment: I know about wikipage.. I want more info on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gil Kalai has a brief writeup here: http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/galvins-proof-of-dinitzs-conjecture/

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [chapter on Dinitz problem](http://books.google.com/books?id=CuTpgZaLahkC&pg=221) in Proofs from the Book.